# Getting an array back from php using $.ajax

Tags: jquery

A php script is giving this array (which has been passed through `json_encode()`)

`[{name:"a1",path:"b1"},{name:"a2",path:"b2"}]`

I use the following function to retrieve the array to jquery:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "functions.php",
data: "action=" + something,
cache: false,
success: function(response) { alert(response); }
});
```

The problem is I get the array back as a string:

`(new String("[{name:"a1",path:"b1"},{name:"a2",path:"b2"}}]"))`

How can I get it to be a javascript array?

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `JSON.parse()`:

```
function(response) { alert(JSON.parse(response)); }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "functions.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: "action=" + something,
cache: false,
success: function(response) { alert(response); }
});
```

Try specifying the data type as JSON.